# Using environment variable in HAProxy config listen isn't working

Tags: variables, configuration, haproxy, environment, portforwarding

here is my simple `listen` section of the haproxy config file:

```
listen graph_front
   bind *:8182
   mode tcp
   server graph_server graph.server.com:8182
```

this works just fine, but I need the address and port to be a environment variable. So I changed it to this:

```
listen graph_front
   bind *:8182
   mode tcp
   server graph_server "$GRAPH_ADDRESS":"$GRAPH_PORT"
```

the haproxy server restarts just fine, but it no longer forwards to the address in the environment variables.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above config was fine. It was the way I was starting haproxy.  I have to start it directly with

`haproxy -f /path/to/config`

this will not work with out elevated privileges. So, next

`sudo haproxy -f /path/to/config`

of course the env variables are not passed through sudo. 
So a more direct way like this works:

`sudo -- sh -c 'export GRAPH_ADDRESS=graph.server.com; export GRAPH_PORT=8182; haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg`